# Running split command in GNU screen conflicts with split Unix utility

Tags: linux, command-line, vim, gnu-screen

I am trying to run the command `split` from within [GNU screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) in order to create a new horizontal region. This command is instead interpreted as a call to the Unix split utility at `/usr/bin/split` for splitting files. The issue is that I want to start screen with a custom configuration using `screen -c custom.conf` where this configuration sets up a split environment of the form:

```
# custom.conf
split
screen 0 
exec some-command-here
focus next
screen 1
exec some-other-command
focus next
```

This custom configuration works fine for every step except the first, where it tries to run the split utility. My question is therefore whether there is: **(a)** another screen command to create a split that doesn't have utility conflicts; **or (b)** a way to call the screen split command that will only be interpreted by screen; **or (c)** a way to bypass the part of PATH containing `/usr/bin/split` for just this command.

*The keyboard bindings for generating a horizontal split work fine, but as far as I'm aware they can't be added to a script*. For further details, I am trying to set up vim for use as an IDE for Python/Julia/etc, following the guide at http://www.juliabloggers.com/vim-as-ide-for-julia/.

The lateral solution to this problem is to use `tmux` or another terminal multiplexer, but I would like to use `screen`. A solution for `tmux` might be:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmux new-session -d -s session_name some-command-here
tmux split-window -t session_name some-other-command
tmux select-pane -t 0
tmux attach-session -t session_name
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a default key binding for split functionality. From `man screen`, "DEFAULT KEY BINDINGS":

```
C-a S (split) Split the current region horizontally into two  new ones.  
See also only, remove, focus.
```

Comment: Yes indeed, but as I detailed in the question I am trying to automate splitting on start up. I do not want to have to type the key binding to create the split, I want to script it to split automatically.

Comment: @Lewis sorry, I will update my answer.